# jquery change label for="" value

Tags: jquery, label

I'm not sure if this is possible, but can jquery change the label "for" value?

Example:

```
<label for="foo">whatever</label>
```

changed to :

```
<label for="bar">whatever</label>
```

I've looked around, but can't seem to find anything..

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can change any attribute, using the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
$("label[for=foo]").attr("for", "bar");
```

Comment: ugh i tried that, but must've done something wrong, because it didn't work.. works now though.. thank you, it's been a long day lol